# How to do a logistic regression with the results of different factor analysis methods

Tags: r, logistic, factor-analysis

I have a large amount of variables (24) to predict a Y/N value, and I would like help for writting a procedure that automatically tries the different results of the factor selection to see how good the regression turns out to be, and of course I want to save the best model for later use.

Comment: You may find helpful those related posts http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/aggregating-results-from-linear-model-runs-r http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/fa-choosing-rotation-matrix-based-on-simple-structure-criteria

Comment: Mallows Cp http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallows'_Cp  Here's a paper on Cp http://mlrv.ua.edu/2008/vol34_1/Lieberman-Morris.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, consider if the factor analysis is the right way to do feature extraction. I would suggest to use principal component analysis to make dimension reduction first and then use extracted features as predictor variables. Depends on your settings you should also use appropriate cross-validation regime to access your prediction.

Comment: I would entirely agree with Andrej. This is one of those rare cases where principal components will probably do a better job than factor analysis.

Comment: Sorry I have one doubt, should I include in PCA the variable I want to predict?

Comment: No, leave your dependent variable (Y/N variable in your case) out of PCA dimension reduction. You can read my article about same topic at the http://goo.gl/lJh5s

Answer (score 0):

You could find useful the 'logisticPCA' package.

Is an R package for dimensionality reduction of binary data.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logisticPCA/vignettes/logisticPCA.html